# my test is not working but not errors

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

```
global class Ops_PmPlanEmail implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful
{
/* pmPlan__c cpm = pmPlan__c.getInstance('replyToAddress');
String reply = cpm.replyTo__c; */ 
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) 
{
String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,DM_E_Mail_ID__c FROM OPS_PmPlan__c';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<OPS_PmPlan__c> scope) 
{ 
List<String> maill=new List<String>(); 
ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O61000001qteI?csv=1');
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
attachment.setFileName('BlankProjects.csv');
attachment.setBody(report.getContent()); 
for(OPS_PmPlan__c mp1:scope)
{ 
List<String> email=new List<String>();
Integer i;
String mail = mp1.DM_E_Mail_ID__c ;
// system.debug(mail);
if(mail!=Null)
{
email = mail.split(','); 
// system.debug(email);
}
for(i=0;i<email.size();i++)
{

maill.add(email[i]);
// system.debug(maill);
}
}
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage smail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 
smail.setBccAddresses(maill);
smail.setReplyTo('Kannan_narayanan01@infosys.com');
String messageBody = 'Dear Delivery Anchor,';
messageBody += '\n';
messageBody += 'One or more projects under your portfolio includes blank project plan. Please take the necessary action.';
smail.setHtmlBody(messageBody); 
smail.setSenderDisplayname('Kannan Narayanan');
smail.setSubject('Blank Project(s)'); 
smail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } ); 
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{smail}); 
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

}

}
```

==============================================

```
@isTest
public class testbatch
{
public static testMethod void testRunAs() 
{

pmPlan__c pm = pmPlan__c.getValues('replytoaddress');
if(pm == Null)
{ 
pm =new Pmplan__c(Name = 'replytoaddress'); 
pm.replyTo__c ='no_rely@salesforce.com'; 
insert pm; 
} 


Attachment attach=new Attachment(); 
attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
attach.body=bodyBlob;
insert attach;


OPS_PmPlan__c op = new OPS_PmPlan__c();
op.DM_E_Mail_ID__c ='pavani.nallamothu@infosys.com,monika.dwadasi@infosys.com,';
insert op;

Test.startTest();
Ops_PmPlanEmail Ops = new Ops_PmPlanEmail (); 
Database.executeBatch(Ops); 
Test.stopTest(); 

} 
}
```

Thanks in advance any help appricated .

Monika.

Comment: (1) Are you sure the `insert op` didn't return an error? (2) As a politeness to the community, you should edit your post and indent your code; (3) Absence of system asserts makes it hard to know if test ran to conclusion as expected although as @hashi points out, emails won't be sent. Using DML in finish() to write a custom Log__c object is a good way to know how a batch job ran

Answer (score 0):

Apex test code don't send mail.
If you want to test your product code, you do execute test in execute anonymous.

Comment: ok but code coverage is zero..for the associated batch class,at least code coverage should be right.

Comment: change test class to 'private'. @isTest available for private class.